# How to deploy a new jar of spring boot without killing the old process of the old jar?

Tags: spring-boot

When after i build the project to a jar,i deploy the jar on my CentOS by type:

```
nohup java -jar ***.jar &
```

But in this way,i must kill the process of the old jar.If not, i'll get error.
So is there any other deployment method?

Comment: where is the problem with killing the process? It sends a shutdown signal to the application which leads to a shutdown. So you can start the new one.

Comment: @YannicKlem killing process needs seconds